# Nagios : webinject using svc

Tags: web-services, nagios, svc

I try to use webinject with nagios to test a Web Services. 
The url is : http://lptvmthdws1:6520/WS_ADVService.svc
Or when i try to test it with webinject i have this issue : Failed HTTP Response Code Verification (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)

I have other WebServices on this server and they work, but the extension is not the same : http://lptvmthdws1:6401/Activation.asmx.

So my question is, if i can use webinject with ".svc" ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.
In my case test, i had an option : addheader="SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/?????/methodToCall"
i catch this information with SoapUI when you execute a request in the section "Raw"
If someone need i can show the code.